# PHP - Trouble with row count displaying same number multiple times, how would I fix this?

Tags: php, mysql

So I am currently working on a project,
And I have a section that has a few numbers and each sub section is supposed to display how records there are or the row count for the specific user. I have managed to display the row count but seem to be having an issue where the row count is displayed 3 times. For example row count = 3 3 3 instead of row count = 3.

```
<?php
    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT banned_players.uuid, player_data.uuid FROM banned_players, player_data WHERE username = :username and banned_players.uuid >= player_data.uuid');
        $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $_GET['name']));
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        //if an error is thrown a message will display
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit();
    }
?>
<?php if ($stmt->rowCount() <1 ): ?>
    0
<?php else: ?>
    <?php while(false !== ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))): ?>
        <?php $count = $stmt->rowCount(); 
        echo $count; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're echoing the row count for every row. So if you have 5 rows, you'll get `5 5 5 5 5`

```
<?php while(false !== ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))): // this starts looping through each row ?> 
    <?php $count = $stmt->rowCount(); 
    echo $count; // this echoes the row count for every row because of the loop ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

If I'm understanding what you want correctly, remove the loop. Or if you need the loop to echo data from the rows, put the row count before or after the loop.

```
Row Count: <?php echo $stmt->rowCount(); ?>
<?php while(false !== ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))): ?>
    Echo some data from $row here
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Oh my lord. How did I not catch that.